# Comparing values from httpclient to a String Android

Tags: php, android, httpclient

I tried to compare http response value from mysql database to a local string but it fails although string are identical.  Have i missed something, a hint might helps perhaps.

```
ResponseHandler<String> handleResponse = new BasicResponseHandler();

String phpEchoVal = httpclient.execute(httppost, handleResponse);

String containEmail = phpEchoVal.toString();

txtInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVInfo);

if ((containEmail.equals("success"))){
  txtInfo.setText(containEmail);
}else {
  txtInfo.setText("Exist");
}
```

Comment: How do you know they're identical?

Comment: Log.d("test","containEmail: "+containEmail); and you will most probably see why.

Comment: the log gives 03-22 12:27:52.903: D/test(304): containEmail: . i believe the containEmail email is not assigned.

Comment: @GrimJov yep.. thats it.. asking why it is not assigned is a completely different question and we will need to see more of your request code in order to help you.. try to make sure your request code is able to return a value try googling for httpresponse snippets

Comment: Thanks for confirmation! In fact it is strange. When i toast the containEmail, strangely, it notifiy me of "success" state from server. Toast.makeText(this, containEmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

Did you add internet permission to your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```